# PrimeNG - TreeNode - make it expand by clicking anywhere, not just on the icon

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-tree

Could anyone show me TreeNode template that makes the whole node clickable (all the label text and icons) and uses the same expand function as the original behavior (when clicking on the icon to expand)? Or do you need to implement your own function doing the expansion onClick?

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz for this, I might be able to help you that way.

Comment: I've just reporposed PrimeNG sample https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tree-demo-zskodv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

My goal is to be able to click the the folder icon and label, not just the triangle

Answer (score 0):

I've used it in one of projects some time ago, if I recall correctly (nodeSelect) and (nodeExpand) was using almost the same logic so it expands on selection and expanstion.